# Hibernate criteria to return result in a map

Tags: hibernate

I have a user table, how do I create a `Criteria` in Hibernate that returns a Map with the UserId as the key and the User object as the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, cause a query always returns a List: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#list() 
or in a special case a single element.

There is just no method that could return a map.

So without hacks like overwriting the Session to create a special Criteria which also has a map() method you can't do what you want.

Just return a list and convert it into a map.

Answer (score 0):

Using Google guava

```
ImmutableMap<Long, User> immutableMap = Maps.<Long, User>uniqueIndex(hibernateSession.createCriteria(User.class).list(),
                    new Function<User, Long>() {
                        public Long apply(User input) {
                            return input.getId();
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Awesome to know! But I was looking for a solution that doesn't use another library.

Comment: I know what you mean. I use Guava for loads of stuff so it adds no additional dependencies.

Comment: well tbh, either way it will go that route. cuz either hibernate returns a map or you convert to map. once you centralised the map conversion there is no big diff at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HQL , which has 
`new map`
to return the required data in the form of map. If you can use this, then I am happy to share further details on how to do this.